# Where can I find my edit profile file

Tags: theming

I'll try to make this as simple as possible.

I use Drupal Commons and want to add this code:

```
if (module_exists('user_badges')) {
    print user_badges_for_uid($uid);
}
```

to my profile user's profile page.

Does anyone know where I can find that?

What I want to do: https://www.drupal.org/node/942014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not used this particular distro, or module... there's not a block that already contains the user badges? There are several places you could add the code, there might be more:

- Add a [user_profile.tpl.php template to your theme](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user-profile.tpl.php/7.x), add the code in there.
- [Create a simple custom block with the code](https://www.fourkitchens.com/blog/article/building-custom-blocks-drupal-7/). You might have to get a reference to the User. I think your module would have to provide that (I don't think it is in the variables available to blocks)
- [Using a preprocess function for the profile](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.pages.inc/function/template_preprocess_user_profile/7.x) in your theme. Might best work in combination with the tpl.
- (not recommended) [uses php filter](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/howtos/add-php-code-to-the-body-of-a-drupal-7-block), and put the php directly in a block.

Comment: The block does. But only "My badges"

Comment: I would think that "my badges" would be doing what you want -- showing the badges of the user on their user profile page.

Comment: Yes but I want to show users other users badges.

Comment: Oh, I see... yeah, so one of the above!